# Using Apache virtual hosts with Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, apache2

My site was originally 2 html pages separated as such:

```
<VirtualHost site.a.org:443>
    ServerName site.a.org
    <Directory >
        DirectoryIndex  a.html       
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost site.b.org:443>
    ServerName site.b.org
    <Directory>
        DirectoryIndex  b.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

a.html and b.html were practically duplicates of each other, with different branding.  I've since introduced Angular ui-router, and now the URLs are

- site.org/#/a
- site.org/#/b

Is it possible to keep the site.a.org and site.b.org URLs and have them point to the Angular routes?  The goal is to not affect the users who have already bookmarked the URLs, and I lack the understanding of apache url rewriting  Thanks!

Comment: As you entered the "fake" site names, are you switching between .org and .com accidentally?

Comment: I apologize, they should all be consistent with the .org extension.  It was something I overlooked when editing the URLs.